# Return only non zero elements in the array

Tags: loops, while-loop, iteration

In the code given below, I want to get an array in which there should not be non zero elements. if in the iteration any zero value found, the code should jump to new iteration and loop should run till code returns non zero elements in the array. Above mentioned problem is the requirement od code so no shortcut can be used, ### editings are welcome

```
count = 0;
    while (1)
        x = randi([0 10],1,5); 
        for i = 1:length(x)       
        if x(i) == 0
            continue
        end
        end
        count = count +1;    
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
clear all;
count = 0;
while (1)
    x = randi([0 10],1,5);
    for i = 1:length(x)       
    if x(i) ~= 0
        continue
    elseif x(i) == 0
        return
    end
    end
    count = count +1;
    display(x)  
end
```